# How can I default WPF Items to private instead of internal?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I would like all WPF XAML items to default to private instead of internal.
Is this possible within Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might vote for the bug on Microsoft Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/473651/xaml-x-name-should-create-fields-with-access-modifier-private